# Why in Britain do we stop for a 'coffee', but a 'cup of tea'?

Tags: idioms, word-usage, british-english

In polite company in Britain one asks ones guest if they have time for *a coffee* - usually if it is morning. But if it is afternoon one would ask them if they would like a *cup of tea*.

Now this is not about why we drink coffee in the morning and tea in the afternoon, but why it is that we elide *cup of* when speaking of coffee, but that it is essentially included when speaking of *tea*.

Comment: We can drink coffee mostly with plastic or paper cups nowadays while we drink tea only in "traditional ceramic cups"? Coffee is now mostly used as "countable" noun, I guess,  although it used to be uncountable.

Comment: @Rathony But we can and do drink tea out of plastic cups too. But I am not really talking about places where you can do that. In *Kath's Kafe* or *Tesco's cafeteria* we may well ask for two teas, and one coffee (except that nowadays coffee in such places has evolved a dreadful foreign nomenclature involving latte, cappuccino, etc). But I am talking here about such as tea with the vicar. Now there you would be offered a *cup of tea*, or a *coffee*.

Comment: I agree. Just a trend, I guess.

Comment: @Rathony I don't think it is a 'trend'. It has always been the case as long as I remember - which is quite a while!

Comment: I believe it is just a preference which to use. I prefer using coffee as a countable noun and using tea as an uncountable noun. Maybe there are more people who share the same preference.

Comment: Because tea is ceremonial, and the cup is a more important part of the the ceremony than the tea itself.

Comment: I have never managed to grow accustomed to using the names of liquids as count nouns: *beer, water, coffee, milk, tea,* etc. I had never heard such a thing as a child, and when I encountered it in speakers from other states when I hit college, I thought it sounded foreign or wrong, or at best the language of a waitress at a cheap diner calling out an order.

Comment: I've mostly heard "cuppa" or "cuppa coffee" for a cup of coffee; never just "coffee" by itself...

Comment: @Julia As I understand it you are Australian, Julia. And you do a lot of things differently. I think it was your Prime Minister Gough Whitlam, when he went to the Buckingham Palace garden party, drank beer out of a can. I have lived in Australia, and culturally I felt very much at home. Sydney was just like working-class London, where indeed you would ask for a *cuppa* or a *cuppa coffee*. But I am talking here about people who drink their tea or coffee with their little finger extended.

Comment: In the US, we tend not to say "*a* coffee" but "a cup of coffee" when an invitation is involved. *Do you have time to stay for a cup of coffee?*  The phrase "a coffee" in the context of an invitation seems to me to be a Britishism.

Comment: But I should add that we *do* say "Do you have time for *a quick coffee*?" which goes, I think, to the suggestion by HotLicks that tea has a ceremonial quality.  (In some countries coffee is ceremonial.)

Comment: @TimRomano Would that also apply to *a beer*,*a sherry*, *a whisky* etc? Curiously we don't though say *a wine*. We would say *glass of wine*.

Comment: @WS2: Sherry isn't drunk much here in the US -- the local state monopoly doesn't have a single medium dry sherry on the shelves, for example, no Amontillado, only sweet dessert sherries.  But we do invite guests for "a beer".  I don't think "a whisk(e)y" is used much in invitations; it would tend to be "a glass of whisk(e)y" or "some whisk(e)y" like "a glass of wine".

Comment: @TimRomano That's interesting about *a quick coffee* - because that's exactly what we would say. But we wouldn't say *a quick tea*. But we might say *a quick cuppa*, or *a quick cup of tea*.

Comment: @WS2: In my mother's family, Philadelphia Irish, guests are invited to "stay for a quick cup of tea" but it usually goes on for hours and invariably involves cinnamon buns and crumb cake.  Litotes?

Comment: @TimRomano I had never before realised that whilst in Britain it is *whisky* in the USA it is *whiskey*. Original is the Gaelic *uisgebetha* - the water of life. But I fell sure I didn't need explain that to an Irishman!

Comment: Does it have anything to do with class?  I remember an episode of "Upstairs, Downstairs" in which Belgian refugees (WWI)  taken on as part of staff at Eaton Place asked for coffee, and the Downstairs staff were outraged.  Coffee was for Upstairs, tea was for Downstairs.

Comment: @WS2 Scots Gaelic is "uisge beatha", anglicised as "whisky"; Irish is "uisce beatha", anglicised as "whiskey" — as far as I know, the spelling is particular to the drink though rather than the region, e.g. I'd say Glenlivet is a whisky (Scotch); but Bushmills is a whiskey. Not sure if there's a formal adoption of either spelling for Bourbon though — e.g. Maker's Mark uses 'whisky', Jim Bean uses 'whiskey'.

Comment: @ab2 That was certainly the case. The British working class did not start drinking coffee until the 1960s. I remember my own parents in the 1950s never had coffee in the house, other than a dreadful brand called *Camp coffee* which others of my age will remember. Nowadays most people drink coffee but Britain remains a big tea-drinking nation. But none of this has anything to do with why the gentile classes refer to *a coffee* but *a cup of tea*.

Comment: @HotLicks Tea has never been ceremonial in Britain, at least not in the formal way that it is in such as Japan or China.

Comment: @WS2 - Not in the sense of an actual ceremony, but in the sense of a social occasion.  I recall reading that the British prisoners of the Japanese in WWII would have "tea time" even when they could only pour cold water into tin cups.  The cup is (or was) more important than the tea.

Comment: @HotLicks They also may have done it with a deep sense of irony. 'Having a cup of tea' certainly goes beyond its value as a physical refreshment. I once heard of an occasion during the first Gulf war (1991 ?) when some British squaddies were showing some US military brass one of their Challenger tanks. There was an unusual device on the side which intrigued one of the Americans, who was a Lieutenant Colonel and tank commander. 'What's this for?' the officer asked. 'It's for making a cuppa tea' he was told by a Cockney accented Corporal.

Comment: @Rathony Coffee out of a paper cup? You heathen! It's dark green porcelain with a gold rim or nothing!

Answer (score 8):

Because in British usage, *tea* can also mean a light meal taken in the afternoon.

By taking a *cup of tea*, we are differentiating the action from taking *tea*.  We are not offering to provide a meal.

There is no meal called *coffee*, so a *cup of coffee* can be considered to be redundant.

Comment: I had been considering this myself and there may be something in it. Anyway it is worth a vote. But you also have to consider that we talk about having *a beer*, *a sherry* or *a whisky*, but never *a wine* , rather *a glass of wine*. So I think there is something more to it than what you suggest.

Comment: @WS2   An interesting series of cultural associations and usages.  There's a suggestion that offering  _tea_ or _having tea_ creates an ambiguity in countries where _tea_ is also refers to an evening meal. On the same basis an invitation to _have a wine_ might in some contexts be misunderstood to be an invitation to express an opinion (whine), or be very well understood (but incorrectly) as a pejorative observation about the character of a person so addressed.  But in respect of _beer_ , we equally might understand what is meant when offered a _pint_ and know that we don't mean milk.

Comment: @JohnMack Would you care for a whine? I hadn't thought of that - but rather like it! What a hilarious sense of ambiguity you have.